# Why does Perl's DateTime throw an error when trying to add() time with the 'hour' option?

Tags: perl

I'm trying to add an hour to the current time but am getting an error.

My code snippet is

```
use DateTime;
my $now=DateTime->now(
     time_zone=> 'America/Los_Angeles');
$now->add( hour=>1 );
```

The error I get is:

```
The following parameter was passed in the call to DateTime::Duration::new but was not listed in the validation options: day at c:\strawberry....
DateTime::Duration::new(undef, 'day', 1) called at c:\strawberry.... 
DateTime::add('DateTime=HASH(0x2e49ae0)', 'day', 1) called at tester.pl line 6
```

How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By changing your call to

```
$now->add( hours => 1 );
```

Comment: so obvious in retrospect.  Stupid humans (or at least English speakers) why would you have a different word when quantity!=1?

Comment: @Dean: It's a long standing, multi-language tradition to have different forms of the same word.  See French, Spanish, Russian (oh man, Russian...)

Comment: @RobertP: yeah, I think Asian languages don't do plural forms, or at least not Vietnamese and Japanese.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the [`DateTime`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime) `add` method documentation:

> $dt->add( DateTime::Duration->new parameters )
>
> This method is syntactic sugar around the add_duration() method. It simply creates a new DateTime::Duration object using the parameters given, and then calls the add_duration() method.

Oh, so it just is like calling add_duration.  What does the `DateTime->add_duration` method say?

> $dt->add_duration( $duration_object )
>
> This method adds a DateTime::Duration to the current datetime. See the DateTime::Duration docs for more details.

Ah, we need parameters for a DateTime::Duration.  What are those?

http://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime::Duration

```
use DateTime::Duration;

$dur = DateTime::Duration->new(
   years       => 3,
   months      => 5,
   weeks       => 1,
   days        => 1,
   hours       => 6,
   minutes     => 15,
   seconds     => 45,
   nanoseconds => 12000
);
```

Oh, `hour` ne `hours`.  Use

```
$now->add( hours => 1 );
```

instead!